# Is there a way to set a field back to prior value on rejection of approval?

Tags: approval-process

Is there a way to set a field back to prior value on rejection of approval?

Comment: You could instead not change the field until it has been approved, like suggested here... https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1AcAAI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set back a field value of field A to it's prior value after rejection, you would have to "stamp" the prior value on another field (field B) somewhere in the background. This can be done using a [workflow rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_examples.htm) with field update: Update the field B with the value of field A once it changes - use the ISCHANGED function.

You could then write another workflow rule (or even a field update as part of your [Final Rejection actions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_final_rejection_actions.htm&language=en)) to update your field back to it's prior value once the rejection occurs.